# How to escape/encode a comma in a nginx location block

Tags: nginx

I want to exact match a URL that includes a comma, in an nginx location block. The link has been formed incorrectly from two comma separated URLs and I would like to redirect to the correct (first) URL rather than return a 404 error.

This is what I tried first:

```
location = /page_one,page_two {
    return 301 https://example.com/page_one;
}
```

I have also tried escaping the comma with a slash `\,` and encoding it as `%2C` and all of the above with the URL in double quotes.

I would prefer an exact match solution if it is possible, rather than a prefix or regular expression match.

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: The problem I had was the location block not matching a URL and I thought this was due to the presence of a comma but was actually due to double slashes in the path component.

Comment: You really shouldn't use commas in your url.

Comment: I haven’t. I’m trying to redirect an incorrect link generated somewhere else that I don’t have control over.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the problem was not with the comma but with double slashes in the URL path component. These are interpreted by nginx as a single slash.

A better example of the link would have been:

`https://example.com/page_one,https://example.org/page_two`

Which at example.com, I am now matching and redirecting with:

```
location = /page_one,https:/example.org/page_two {
    return 301 https://example.com/page_one;
}
```

So the comma does not need to be escaped in this situation but the double slashes are matched by a single slash.